# Need help identifying this frame

Tags: shimano, vintage

I have this bike that I am trying to sell. I have trouble finding out the exact brand of the frame itself but I think I figured out some of the parts (please correct me if I am wrong)

handle bar: SR (sakae ringyo)
crank: SR
wheel frame: made in canada
some shimano components
and a thunderbird component[image]

Comment: Did you get some info from the original owner?

Comment: What does it say on the headbadge? I expect it's a Competition Finalist! not really search engine friendly

Comment: we could use some more photos - particularly the head tube badge

Comment: It comes from that era where people sold bikes with stickers saying "ultra-light", "Sports", "Competition", none of which were really qualities of the bike.